# How to see where my web page is being called from (where it's embedded)?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to change some styling on my webpage based on if it's being called from one website it's embedded in vs the other (as an iframe). I looked up a bunch of stuff about it; uri, requests, httprequests, using the "object sender", but nothing seemed to show any differences. I am trying to do this inside the "Site.Master.cs" in asp.net. Any help or tips are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `HttpContext.Request` object. Has lots of properties about the requestor,

specifically `HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer`,`HttpContext.Request.UserAgent`, `HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress` and `HttpContext.Request.UserHostName`

Check out the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.request?view=netframework-4.8)